# useState stays undefined after axios get fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch, setstate

I've cut down the code to the needed parts.

getArticleFromApi gets called onSubmit (apiData works fine)

My Problem ist that the console.log returns undefined after the FIRST click of submit.

if i hit it AGAIN a few Seconds later everything works as expected.

My Question is how can i make JS wait until article is no longer undefined.
Until state article is set. (delay execution of code)

```
import {useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const [apiData, setApiData] = useState();
const [article, setArticle] = useState();

const getArticleFromApi = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/articles/' + apiData.brand_id + '/' + apiData.article_number)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    .then(resp => {
      setArticle(resp.data.data)
    })
    console.log(article)
}
```

This is my first Question so go soft on me. Tell me if i can improve anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `setState` is a asynchronous function, you can not get a newly changed state right after `setState`.

Check out [offical docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value) about this topic.

One way to log the changing of the state is to set a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect) function with `article`.

```
const getArticleFromApi = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/articles/' + apiData.brand_id + '/' + apiData.article_number)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    .then(resp => {
      setArticle(resp.data.data)
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(article)
}, [article])
```

Every time `article` changes, `useEffect` will run the callback function, which will log the latest `article`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const [apiData, setApiData] = useState();
const [article, setArticle] = useState();
const [extra,setExtra]=useState(0) // add this line

const getArticleFromApi = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/articles/' + apiData.brand_id + '/' + apiData.article_number)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    .then(resp => {
      setArticle(resp.data.data)
      setExtra(extra+1)  // add this line
  
    })
    console.log(article)
}


useEffect(()=>{
getArticleFromApi()
},[])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).